# Behavior During Phone Calls in Mobile Chrome Browser: Pausing and Stop Issues

Tags: android, google-chrome, video, mobile, playback

During a phone call on Android mobile phones, there is an issue where the video in the mobile Chrome browser's video tag is not executed. Upon observation, it has been found that the Chrome browser interrupts the video playback at intervals shorter than 0.1 seconds while using the default phone app on Android during a call.

Interestingly,

1. The video does not pause if it is started before making a phone call.
2. This issue is not present in Safari or Samsung Internet browsers.

Are there any known issues or solutions related to this behavior?

Check out the test sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mobile Video Player</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-container">
        <video id="video-master" controls>
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```